# NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate not called when merging ManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I'm using Core Data on multiple threads, so I create a ManagedObjectContext for each thread. When I save the MOC-Thread I perform a merge so the modifications are available in MOC-main.

When changing an already existing managed object, the NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate event isn't called for my NSFetchResultsControllers. However when I insert or delete a managed object, the events for my NSFetchResultsController are called. Only not for updates.

Someone familiar with this problem?